# How can i get user sessions per day/hour from Google Analytics (GA4)

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Actually, I'm very new in Google Analytics API field (GA4.)

Based on my Topics "How can i get user sessions per day/hour from Google Analytics (GA4)"

Do I need to get session per day & hour separately ?. Or should I get per hour only ?

Because I have found that session per day & hour from GA4 is not consistent (per hour x 24 != per day )

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask]  Edit your question.  Show what information you are trying to access, links to documentation is good.   Include [example] and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.